# How to remove the filter from GPUImageView

Tags: android, gpuimage

I have developed a little application using `GPUImage`. I set a filter to `GPUImageView` and the image changed, but how can I remove the filter to see the real image?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Assuming you're using the following library: https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage*

Checking at the source code of the abovementioned library you should simply be able to do something like this:

```
GPUImageView v ...

v.setFilter(new GPUImageFilter(GPUImageFilter.NO_FILTER_VERTEX_SHADER, GPUImageFilter. NO_FILTER_FRAGMENT_SHADER));
```

which is equivalent to

```
v.setFilter(new GPUImageFilter());
```

Since the class has an alternative constructor:

```
public GPUImageFilter() {
    this(NO_FILTER_VERTEX_SHADER, NO_FILTER_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
}
```

with the default values already applied.

Let me know if that worked out for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried this morning and it worked! Thanks again! By the way, your assuming is right.

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thanks!

Comment: @FelixNovovic How can i detect specific filter a list of filters in group filter and remove that specific filter?

Comment: But is show black are which is already transparent. not orignal image I got.